# C Socket Write Too many times

Tags: c, sockets, read-write

After the user as entered data it writes out a part of the data entered before the data just enetered if that makes sense? I've only included a snippet, but can anyone see any reason why it would reply multiple times?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h> // write

#include<pthread.h> // For Threading

#include<wiringPi.h>
void *connection_handler(void *);
void lightLED(int pin,int status);
int maxConnections = 1;
int totalConnections = 0;
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *message;     
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
     if(new_socket > 0)
     {
      if(totalConnections < maxConnections){
      totalConnections++;
     }
      else
      {
       message = "Sorry Maximum Users Reached\n";
       write(new_socket,message,strlen(message));
       puts("Too many Users");
       close(new_socket);
       continue;
      }
    }
     puts("Connection Accepted");
    char *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
    int client_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);
    printf("ClientIP:%s\n",client_ip);
     message = "Hello you have been accepted!\n";
     write(new_socket, message , strlen(message));

    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    new_sock = malloc(1);
    *new_sock = new_socket;

    if(pthread_create( &sniffer_thread, NULL , connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) <0)
    {
     perror("Could not create thread");
    return 1;
    }
    puts("Handler Assigned");
    }

    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    message = "Greeting! I am your Connection Handler\n";
    write(sock , message,strlen(message));

    message =  "What do you want to do\n";
    write(sock,message,strlen(message));

    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0)
    {
     write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
     printf("User Entered:%s\n",client_message);
     int pin = client_message[0]-'0';
     int status = client_message[1]-'0';
     lightLED(pin,status);
    }
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
    puts("Client Disconnected\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    totalConnections--;
    }else if(read_size == -1)
    {
     perror("recv Failed");
    }

    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}

void lightLED(int pin,int status)
{
    char message;
    if(wiringPiSetup() == -1){
    puts("wiringPi Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    //pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);
    printf("Changing LED Pin- %d Status- %d\n",pin,status);
    //digitalWrite(pin,status);
}
```

Comment: You don't check that any of your `write()` calls succeed; that could be a problem.  You get told the size of the message you've just read off the socket; you then write back a message using `strlen()` to determine the size. However, your writes do not include a null terminator, so there's no reason to expect the data read to include a null terminator, so you could be writing all sorts of garbage. The `printf()` is also probably printing garbage too. It's a little odd to echo back what the client sent, unchanged, unvalidated. Shouldn't you wait to respond until you've checked `lightLED()`?

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah the reason its like so as i was using it as a test, replying what was sent just to test it works both ends. How would you recommend using the information that is received?    'lightLED()' needs to take 2 ints as you can see.

Comment: Does `lightLED()` return a status indicating whether it was able to perform the request?  Was the LED number valid?  Was the request valid?  Echoing received data is good; doing it correctly is better.  A log file (or standard output instead, as with the `printf()`) is a good place to record the details.  Echoing back to the client is OK if the protocol permits it — you did realize you are designing a protocol, didn't you?  One advantage of designing your own is you can make it work as you want, of course.  You accept up to 2000 characters; you only use 2 characters.  That's quite a disparity.

Comment: yeah i realised i was moving into making a protocol kind of...
i had started with a basic version and hadnt changed the amount of characters etc. seeing as when trying to send the Pin and Status to the lightLED works fine...but when i disconnect it then sends information to it twice more, which is why ive focussed on that issue.

Comment: Is this the 'main function' for a POSIX pthread?  The interface looks like it might be.  Are you sure that only one thread is using the given socket?  If multiple threads are using the same socket, there might be issues.

Comment: ive made it so only one connection is allowed at a time. I will post the whole file.

Comment: Have added the whole file. Try not to laugh too much

Comment: You are using strlen to determine the message length. Are you receiving '\0' terminated strings from the client, in recv()? Because if not, its a good idea to memset the client_message[] with zeros before using it.

Alternatively, you could use the size recv() gives you, to write the message into the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First pass

I'm not sure what problem you're seeing.  I've taken your code (which was in pretty good shape — well done; I've looked at a lot of code with many worse problems in it) and compiled it and run it and it seemed to work for me:

```
$ nc localhost 8888
Connection Accepted
ClientIP:127.0.0.1
Handler Assigned
Hello you have been accepted!
Greeting! I am your Connection Handler
What do you want to do
01
User Entered:01

Changing LED Pin- 0 Status- 1
01
21
User Entered:21

Changing LED Pin- 2 Status- 1
21
31
User Entered:31

Changing LED Pin- 3 Status- 1
31
we wish you a merry Christmas
User Entered:we wish you a merry Christmas

Changing LED Pin- 71 Status- 53
we wish you a merry Christmas
Client Disconnected

$
```

The code as run was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
//#include <wiringPi.h>

void *connection_handler(void *);
void lightLED(int pin, int status);

int maxConnections = 1;
int totalConnections = 0;

int main(void)
{
    int socket_desc, new_socket, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char *message;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if ( bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    if (listen(socket_desc, 3) != 0)
    {
        perror("listen() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while ((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)))
    {
        if (new_socket > 0)
        {
            if (totalConnections < maxConnections)
                totalConnections++;
            else
            {
                message = "Sorry Maximum Users Reached\n";
                write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));
                puts("Too many Users");
                close(new_socket);
                continue;
            }
        }
        puts("Connection Accepted");
        char *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
        //int client_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);

        printf("ClientIP:%s\n", client_ip);
        message = "Hello you have been accepted!\n";
        write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));       // Oops!
        if (new_sock == 0) { perror("out of memory"); return 1; }
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if (pthread_create( &sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void*) new_sock) <0)
        {
            perror("Could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Handler Assigned");
    }

    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message, client_message[2000];

    message = "Greeting! I am your Connection Handler\n";
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));

    message =  "What do you want to do\n";
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));

    while ((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
    {
        write(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message));
        printf("User Entered:%s\n", client_message);
        int pin = client_message[0]-'0';
        int status = client_message[1]-'0';
        lightLED(pin, status);
    }
    if (read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client Disconnected\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        totalConnections--;
    }
    else if (read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv Failed");
    }

    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}

void lightLED(int pin, int status)
{
//    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
//    {
//        puts("wiringPi Error");
//        exit(1);
//    }

    printf("Changing LED Pin- %d Status- %d\n", pin, status);
}
```

If you still have problems, maybe the trouble is in your client code.  As you can see, I used `netcat` (`nc`) as a surrogate for your client.  Note that 'we wish you a merry Christmas' was accepted as a valid command, though the pin was 73 and the status was 53.  That might not work with the real LEDs.

Note that I added an error check for the `malloc()` and allocated a more correct amount of space (`sizeof(int)` instead of just 1 byte).  I also made sure that reported error conditions are followed by a more-or-less appropriate error return, rather than continuing as if no error had occurred.

Also, I've not fixed some of the issues highlighted in the comments — checking `write()` and not relying on null termination, etc.  These should still be addressed.

My test was on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with GCC 4.7.1:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition server.c -o server
```

---

### Second pass

Another test run — showing the problem with inputs that are not null terminated:

```
$ nc localhost 8888
Connection Accepted
ClientIP:127.0.0.1
Hello you have been accepted!
Handler Assigned
Greeting! I am your Connection Handler
What do you want to do
this is a long string - what will you do with it?
User Entered:this is a long string - what will you do with it?

Changing LED Pin- 68 Status- 56
this is a long string - what will you do with it?
01
User Entered:01
s is a long string - what will you do with it?

Changing LED Pin- 0 Status- 1
01
s is a long string - what will you do with it?
Client Disconnected

$
```

When I ran it with `telnet` instead of `nc`, I got the misbehaviour you were seeing, I think:

```
$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connection Accepted
ClientIP:127.0.0.1
Handler Assigned
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello you have been accepted!
Greeting! I am your Connection Handler
What do you want to do
Would you like a biscuit?
User Entered:Would you like a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- 39 Status- 63
Would you like a biscuit?
93
User Entered:93
d you like a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- 9 Status- 3
93
d you like a biscuit?
Intriguing
User Entered:Intriguing
ke a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- 25 Status- 62
Intriguing
ke a biscuit?
Bye
User Entered:Bye
guing
ke a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- 18 Status- 73
Bye
guing
ke a biscuit?
User Entered:ye
guing
ke a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- -44 Status- 73
ye
guing
ke a biscuit?
^CUser Entered:????guing
ke a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- -49 Status- -60
User Entered:???guing
ke a biscuit?

Changing LED Pin- -49 Status- -53
?guing
ke a biscuit?
User Entered:??guing
ke a biscuit?

...continued attempts with control-C (interrupt)...
...and control-D (EOF) not producing anything useful...

^]
telnet> qConnection closed.
Client Disconnected

$
```

So, `telnet` may have been misleading you...nothing up with your server, just the client (`telnet`) not behaving as you expected.

#### Updated code

Conversation with updated server code:

```
$ nc localhost 8888
Connection Accepted
ClientIP: 127.0.0.1
Handler Assigned
Hello you have been accepted!
Greetings! I am your Connection Handler
What do you want to do
13
User Entered:13

Changing LED Pin 1 status 3
13
21
User Entered:21

Changing LED Pin 2 status 1
21
elephants?
User Entered:elephants?

Changing LED Pin 53 status 60
elephants?
21
User Entered:21

Changing LED Pin 2 status 1
21
quit 
User Entered:quit

Changing LED Pin 65 status 69
quit
Client Disconnected

$
```

#### Updated server code

This version pays attention to lengths and ensures that strings are null terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
//#include <wiringPi.h>

void *connection_handler(void *);
void lightLED(int pin, int status);
static void write_sock(int sock, const char *msg);

int maxConnections = 1;
int totalConnections = 0;

int main(void)
{
    int socket_desc, new_socket, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    if (listen(socket_desc, 3) != 0)
    {
        perror("listen() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while ((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)))
    {
        if (new_socket > 0)
        {
            if (totalConnections < maxConnections)
                totalConnections++;
            else
            {
                write_sock(new_socket, "Sorry Maximum Users Reached\n");
                puts("Too many Users");
                close(new_socket);
                continue;
            }
        }

        puts("Connection Accepted");
        char *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
        //int client_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);

        printf("ClientIP: %s\n", client_ip);
        write_sock(new_socket, "Hello you have been accepted!\n");

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));       // Oops!
        if (new_sock == 0) { perror("out of memory"); return 1; }
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if (pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void *)new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("Could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Handler Assigned");
    }

    if (new_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Avoid repetition - use functions!
static void write_sock(int sock, const char *msg)
{
    int len = strlen(msg);
    if (write(sock, msg, len) != len)
    {
        perror("short write on socket");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char client_message[2000];

    write_sock(sock, "Greetings! I am your Connection Handler\n");
    write_sock(sock, "What do you want to do\n");

    while ((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
    {
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';
        write_sock(sock, client_message);
        printf("User Entered:%s\n", client_message);
        int pin = client_message[0]-'0';
        int status = client_message[1]-'0';
        lightLED(pin, status);
    }

    if (read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client Disconnected\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        totalConnections--;
    }
    else if (read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv Failed");
    }

    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}

void lightLED(int pin, int status)
{
//    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
//    {
//        puts("wiringPi Error");
//        exit(1);
//    }
    printf("Changing LED Pin %d status %d\n", pin, status);
}
```

Note the use of the `write_sock()` function to encapsulate repeated code (which has the side benefit of only requiring the code to be written once, so it can be correct every time it is used).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
//#include <wiringPi.h>

void *connection_handler(void *);
void lightLED(int pin, int status);
static void write_sock(int sock, const char *msg);

int maxConnections = 1;
int totalConnections = 0;

int main(void)
{
    int socket_desc, new_socket, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    if (listen(socket_desc, 3) != 0)
    {
        perror("listen() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while ((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)))
    {
        if (new_socket > 0)
        {
            if (totalConnections < maxConnections)
                totalConnections++;
            else
            {
                write_sock(new_socket, "Sorry Maximum Users Reached\n");
                puts("Too many Users");
                close(new_socket);
                continue;
            }
        }

        puts("Connection Accepted");
        char *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
        //int client_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);

        printf("ClientIP: %s\n", client_ip);
        write_sock(new_socket, "Hello you have been accepted!\n");

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));       // Oops!
        if (new_sock == 0) { perror("out of memory"); return 1; }
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if (pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void *)new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("Could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Handler Assigned");
    }

    if (new_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Avoid repetition - use functions!
static void write_sock(int sock, const char *msg)
{
    int len = strlen(msg);
    if (write(sock, msg, len) != len)
    {
        perror("short write on socket");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char client_message[2000];

    write_sock(sock, "Greetings! I am your Connection Handler\n");
    write_sock(sock, "What do you want to do\n");

    while ((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
    {
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';
        write_sock(sock, client_message);
        printf("User Entered:%s\n", client_message);
        int pin = client_message[0]-'0';
        int status = client_message[1]-'0';
        lightLED(pin, status);
    }

    if (read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client Disconnected\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        totalConnections--;
    }
    else if (read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv Failed");
    }

    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}

void lightLED(int pin, int status)
{
//    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
//    {
//        puts("wiringPi Error");
//        exit(1);
//    }
    printf("Changing LED Pin %d status %d\n", pin, status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I shall try it. 

I have been doing it in Telnet, when i tried it in nc it worked well. Do you fancy trying it in Telnet and you may see that when you close the connection client end the server has 2 more messages it received with the numbers -44

Comment: -44 is `^D - '0'`; `telnet` was sending the control-D uninterpreted.

Comment: ahh ok so the bain of life right now..telnet. Thanks for you help